# Prompted "kAMDMobileImageMounterDeviceLocked" when I'm debugging on real device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10

I'm getting an error that I upgraded my iPhone OS to the latest iOS 10 beta3. But it prompted the window alert "kAMDMobileImageMounterDeviceLocked" when I'm running my application in Xcode 7.3.1 on Mac OS 10.11.5. I need help by you.

[image]

Comment: upgrade to iOS 10 beta 3 and Xcode 8 beta 3

Comment: @RohanKhude Yeah, but I don't want to use of Xcode 8 beta 3, my project is used to running well in Xcode 7.3.1.

Comment: I just want to know how does it's running well on iOS 10 beta while using Xcode 7.3.1